# Of people who develop Alzheimer disease, are those people genetically predisposed to it?

Tags: microbiology, brain, pathology, neurology, neurodegenerative-disorders

I have read a lot lately about microbiological pathogens that are found in blood vessels in the brain of patient's with Alzheimer disease (positive association).
So, I am confused whether there are genetic markers and testing of susceptibility to this disease, or whether there is some other type of disease process occurring here (given the microbiological pathogens association). Is that widely discussed in the popular press?

Comment: In part, there are in fact numerous polymorphic markers that detail genetic predisposition to AD. Markers can differ between the type of AD they predispose, however: familial versus sporadic, for example. To give a good example, of four isoforms the apolipoprotein ε4 isoform is known to greatly increase the chance one will develop AD.